# React Todo Checkbox Styles all listed items at once

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm trying to create a todo-list with React. I am able to display the list in the display area and also able to remove the items. But when I click on one checkbox, all the checkboxes are selected and the class is applied to all the list items. I'm not sure what is it that I am doing wrong.

I tried to use the same logic as I did with the deleted item(that's using the filter), but it doesn't work. I looked other cases here but they are mostly about how to do it with jQuery.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/todo-list-react) is the working example of my problem.

This is the List class

```
class List extends Component {

  state={
    check: false,
    strike: 'none'
  }

  onCheck(item){
    this.setState({check: !this.state.check})
    if (this.state.strike === 'none'){
      this.setState({strike: 'line-through'})
    } else {
      this.setState({strike: 'none'})
    }
  }

  render() {
    const strike = {
      textDecoration: this.state.strike,
    }

  return (
    <ul className='list-style'>
      { this.props.items.map((item, index) =>
         <li key={index}>
           <div className="outer-div">
             <div className="item-checkbox">
               <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.check}
                 onChange={() => this.onCheck(item)} />
              </div>
              <div className="item-text">
                 <span style= {strike}> {item} </span>
              </div>
              <div className="item-remove-div">
                <button className="item-remove" onClick={() => this.props.onDeleteList(index)}>
                  Remove
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
             <br />
         </li>
       )}
    </ul>
  )}
}

export default List;
```

And this is the Main Class:

```
class Main extends Component {

  state = {
    items: [],
    term : "",
  }

 onChange(event){
   this.setState({ term: event });
 }

 onDelete= (item) =>{
   // this.setState ({
   //   items: this.state.items.filter((i) => i.index !== item.index)
   // })
   this.state.items.splice(item, 1);
   this.setState({items: this.state.items});
 }

  onSubmit= (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.term.length > 0){
      this.setState({
        term: '',
        items: [...this.state.items, this.state.term]
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="center">
       <h1 className="header" > TODO-LIST </h1>
       <div className='mainCenter'>
        <form className="App" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <input placeholder="add task" value={this.state.term} onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e.target.value)}
          className="inputField"/>
          <button>Add to the List</button>
        </form>
        <List items={this.state.items}  onDeleteList={this.onDelete}/>
        <div className="footer-outer">
          <span className="footer"> Number of completed items in an array:  {this.state.items.length} </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: stackblitz link is dead.

Comment: The strike state is applied to everything in that loop, it's not specific to the clicked element

Comment: @norbertpy - Thanks! I just edited it. It's working now.

Comment: @SterlingArcher - When I click on one checkbox, all the checkboxes are checked. I thought maybe it was because of that. How would I change that?

Comment: Nice! I'll check now..

Comment: You have a single `check` and `strike` state for all of your List items. You need one pair per each item. Good luck.

Comment: You need to store more info besides the `check` property on List component state. Can I modify your StackBlitz demo?

Comment: @Carloluis Yes, please. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I edited your [SlackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/todo-list-react). Now you can properly add new todos, check individuals tasks (toggle checked on todo click) and see correct `checked` counter in the footer.
Check [todo-list-react](https://todo-list-react.stackblitz.io) demo.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TodoList from './List';
import './style.css';

class Main extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      items: [],
      term: ''
    };
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ term: event.target.value });
  }

  handleItemClick = ({ value, checked }) => {
    this.setState({
      items: this.state.items.map(item => item.value === value ? { value, checked: !checked } : item)
    });
  }

  onSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (this.state.term.length > 0) {
      this.setState({
        term: '',
        items: [...this.state.items, { value: this.state.term, checked: false }]
      });
    }
  }

  handleDelete = index => {
    console.info('todo: remove todo at index', index);
    // deletion logic... keep in mind that using index as key properties on jsx could breaks the correct functioning of this component.
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="center">
       <h1 className="header" > TODO-LIST </h1>
       <div className='mainCenter'>
       <form className="App" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <input placeholder="add task" value={this.state.term} onChange={this.handleChange}
          className="inputField"/>
          <button>Add to the List</button>
        </form>
        <TodoList 
          onTodoClick={this.handleItemClick}
          onDelete={this.handleDelete}
          todos={this.state.items}
        />
        <div className="footer-outer">
          <span className="footer">
            Number of completed items in an array:
            {this.state.items.filter(item => item.checked).length}
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main
```

---

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './style.css';

class List extends Component {
  render() {
    const { todos, onTodoClick, onDelete } = this.props;
    return (
      <ul className='list-style'>
        {
          todos.map((item, index) =>
          <li key={index}>
            <div className="outer-div">
              <div className="item-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" checked={item.checked}
                  onChange={() => onTodoClick(item)} />
                </div>
                <div className="item-text">
                  <span style={checkboxStyle(item.checked)}>{item.value}</span>
                </div>
                <div className="item-remove-div">
                  <button className="item-remove" 
                    onClick={() => onDelete(index)}>
                    Remove
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <br />
          </li>
        )}
      </ul>
    )}
  }

function checkboxStyle(checked) {
  return {
      textDecoration: checked? 'line-through' : 'none',
    };
}

export default List;
```

---

### [image]

In addition to this answer, I recommend you to consider to add an unique `key` property to each jsx-element differen from the array index. Current implementation has no problem, but once you start deleting todo items probably display wrong data.

Read [List and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) from React docs and this article on [Medium](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318) which covers possible error when using indixes as keys.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was very helpful. Although a quick question why do we pass onTodoClick, onDelete, todos as props instead of defining them in the List.js itself?

Comment: You're welcome! I made it that way to keep component responsibilities simple, and avoid state duplication. `<Main>` has the state necessary to accomplish what you want (`items`: todos list, `term`: input's value for next todo).  In React data flows downwards on components tree, and callbacks is the way to notify the parent component of actions inside descendants. I'll update my answer with more info... Also I let you some tips to work with React such as do not make direct mutations on your component's state, etc.

Comment: Thanks! I was playing again with it and I noticed you defined checkboxStyle outside the class instead of inside. I moved it into the List class (added this to the checkboxStyle), and it works the same way. Is there a particular reason you defined it outside? I'm new to web development especially to react so I apologize for bombarding you with all these questions.

Comment: You're welcome. It was a particular decision. I made it that way because I saw the `checkboxStyle` function as an utility, and not as part of the component instance. Also to put the attention focus on the changes that matters in the component's render function.
I think this [react-seed project](https://github.com/UruIT/react-seed) I made would be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that all your list items are being 'striked' is because you have only one state reserved for all the items in the list. You need to have the `checked` or `strike` state for each item in the list. However, as I view your comments, I realize that you already know that.

You have several other inconsistencies in the code:

```
 onDelete= (item) =>{
   this.state.items.splice(item, 1);
   this.setState({items: this.state.items});
 }
```

Making direct changes to the `state` like that might cause unwanted errors and unusual behavior. A better way to do it is to:

```
onDelete = (item) => {
  const items = this.state.items.slice();
  items.splice(item, 1);
  this.setState({
    items: items,
  });
}
```

For more info refer to this article:
https://medium.com/pro-react/a-brief-talk-about-immutability-and-react-s-helpers-70919ab8ae7c

Comment: Thanks! I tried doing it using the filter, but I wasn't able to get the desired result.